# IIS Log 'cs-username' empty

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I need user information in the IIS Log login screen. However, the cs-username value appears as '-' in the IIS logs. I need the value that the user wrote to input.

Is there a way to make the authenticated ASP.NET user's name appear in the username field in the logs?

Comment: *"I need user information in the IIS Log login screen"* - is the user already logged in or **about to** log in?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/no-cs-username-data-advanced-logging

Comment: logged in. I need the log data from which he logged in.

Comment: That field only records user names when Windows/Basic/Digest authentication methods are used. So if you use forms based authentication in ASP.NET, nothing can be showed. Well known for two decades.